# Why the cucumber features keeps running even though it fails?

Tags: rspec, cucumber

Its a rails 2.3.5 app. I'm using the rspec and cucumber for testing.
When I run autospec, it runs correctly with the warning `(Not running features.  To run features in autotest, set AUTOFEATURE=true.)` as below:

```
[~/rails_apps/automation (campaign)⚡] ➔ autospec 
(Not running features.  To run features in autotest, set AUTOFEATURE=true.)
(Not running features.  To run features in autotest, set AUTOFEATURE=true.)
loading autotest/rails_rspec
/home/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:263: warning: `*' interpreted as argument prefix
/home/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/bin/ruby /home/millisami/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/rspec-1.3.0/bin/spec --autospec /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/campaigns_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/board_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/user_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/campaign_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/outlets_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/boards_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/outlet_type_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/vendor_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/brands_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/vendors_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/dashboard_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/brand_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/helpers/dashboard_helper_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/outlet_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/client_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/clients_controller_spec.rb -O spec/spec.opts
```

Now, as it suggests, when I run `AUTOFEATURE=true autospec`, the specs runs and the cuke features as well.
But the problem is that it won't stop. It runs the features and runs them again and again in a loop.
It doesn't stop after it fails. Is this due to the warning `Warning: $KCODE is NONE` as shown below??

```
[~/rails_apps/automation (campaign)⚡] ➔ AUTOFEATURE=true autospec
loading autotest/cucumber_rails_rspec
Warning: $KCODE is NONE.
/home/millisami/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/treetop-1.4.5/lib/treetop/ruby_extensions/string.rb:31: warning: method redefined; discarding old indent
/home/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:263: warning: `*' interpreted as argument prefix
/home/millisami/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:49: warning: method redefined; discarding old blank?
/home/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/bin/ruby /home/millisami/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/rspec-1.3.0/bin/spec --autospec /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/campaigns_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/board_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/user_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/campaign_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/outlets_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/boards_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/outlet_type_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/vendor_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/brands_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/vendors_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/dashboard_controller_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/brand_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/helpers/dashboard_helper_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/outlet_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/models/client_spec.rb /home/millisami/rails_apps/automation/spec/controllers/clients_controller_spec.rb -O spec/spec.opts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autotest checks all files in your rails project after each run and reruns the tests if any modifications are found. You need to add exceptions to your `.autotest` config file to ignore the file(s) that are changing. Here is an example `.autotest`:

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |at|
  %w{.git vendor rerun.txt}.each {|exception| at.add_exception(exception)}
end
```

Cucumber creates `rerun.txt` during its test cycle -- that is probably what's causing your issue. You may need to add additional entries depending on your particular system configuration.

PS. `Autospec` is a wrapper for `autotest`, so if you are having issues with `autospec`, searching on `"autotest"` may get better results. [More about autospec/autotest and Cucumber](http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/autotest-integration).

Comment: @zetetic, Thanks for the reply. I'll look into n get back.

Comment: I tried it and it works somehow.
But whats that warning mean? 

Warning: $KCODE is NONE.

Comment: I had to put some extra folders to make it work.
    Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |at|
      %w{.git vendor rerun.txt tmp log}.each {|exception| at.add_exception(exception)}
    end